# Reduce array of objects to a single object and call a function for each individual object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, iterator, reduce

I've an array of objects.
I need to transform that to object of objects. While trying to do that, I need to call another function for each of the object.

Could you please help me with this?

Code:

```js
function convertData() {
 var arr = {"items": [ {"type": "color"}, {"type": "number" }]};
 arr.items.reduce(function(item, index) {
   return {
    /*for each obj in items call formatItems before assigning it here */
    item: formatItems(item)
   }
 });

  console.log(arr);
}

function formatItems(item, index) {
  return {
    type: "string",
    id: "item-"+index
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="convertData()">Click me!</button>
```

Expected Output:

```
{
  "0": {
    "type": "string",
    "id": "item-1"
  },
  "1": {
    "type": "string",
    "id": "item-2"
  }
}
```

Comment: expected output is wrong. Are you looking for array of objects?

Comment: Your expected output is invalid, it's using object notation, but there are no property names (in the outer object). What is the real desired output?

Comment: "*I need to transform that to object of objects*" would that be an **array** of objects? Or an object that contains properties and each is an object? If the latter, then what should the keys for those be?

Comment: Regarding your edit: that's still invalid. You have one key with an object associated with it but the second one is not correct. Should those be in an array or do you expect two keys?

Comment: BTW, using dynamic `id` properties with sequential numbers could be a code smell. It would be good to know *why* you need this.

Comment: `expected output` is invalid, you can't have `{{}}`, object are storring keys/values pair. It seems that you might want an array `[{}, {}]` or keys for your values: `{key1: {}, hey2: {}}`

Comment: Sorry, my bad! I've updated the expected output.

Comment: @Sunny - Please address the **why** part of trincot's [question above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56114845/reduce-array-of-objects-to-a-single-object-and-call-a-function-for-each-individu#comment98863416_56114845).

Comment: I'm not going to use "id" in the actual code. This is just to create some dummy data to post it here.

Comment: @Sunny - The question is about why you're creating an object with the property names `"0"` and `"1"`, not about `id`. Why not keep using an array?

Comment: I can't use it as an array since I need to further pass the result as an argument to another method, which expects it as an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using an object with property names like `"0"` and `"1"` is really suspect. I'd just keep using an array, which you can readily create via `map` (but keep reading for non-array object options):

```
var result = arr.items.map(formatItems);
```

Live Example:

```js
function convertData() {
  var arr = {"items": [ {"type": "color"}, {"type": "number" }]};
  var result = arr.items.map(formatItems);
  console.log(result);
}

function formatItems(item, index) {
  return {
    type: "string",
    id: "item-"+index
  };
}

convertData();
```

---

But if you really want a non-array object, your code is quite close, if you really want to use `reduce`; see comments:

```
var result = arr.items.reduce(function(obj, item, index) {
  //                                   ^^^-- receive the "accumulator" as the first param
  obj[index] = formatItems(item); // Create the property on the object
  return obj;                     // Return the same object
}, {});                           // Start with a blank object
```

Live Example:

```js
function convertData() {
  var arr = {"items": [ {"type": "color"}, {"type": "number" }]};
  var result = arr.items.reduce(function(obj, item, index) {
    //                                   ^^^-- receive the "accumulator" as the first param
    obj[index] = formatItems(item); // Create the property on the object
    return obj;                     // Return the same object
  }, {});                           // Start with a blank object
  console.log(result);
}

function formatItems(item, index) {
  return {
    type: "string",
    id: "item-"+index
  };
}

convertData();
```

---

**But**, when you're just passing the same object out of the callback as you're receiving, `reduce` isn't the best tool. All you need is a simple loop:

```
var result = {};
for (const [index, item] of arr.items.entries()) {
  result[index] = formatItems(item);
}
```

Live Example:

```js
function convertData() {
  var arr = {"items": [ {"type": "color"}, {"type": "number" }]};
  var result = {};
  for (const [index, item] of arr.items.entries()) {
    result[index] = formatItems(item);
  }
  console.log(result);
}

function formatItems(item, index) {
  return {
    type: "string",
    id: "item-"+index
  };
}

convertData();
```

[Adiga has a **much** simpler ES2015+ option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56115131/157247), though.

---

Or if you need a pre ES2015 version:

```
var result = {};
for (int index = 0; index < arr.items.length; ++index) {
  result[index] = formatItems(arr.items[index]);
}
```

Live Example:

```js
function convertData() {
  var arr = {"items": [ {"type": "color"}, {"type": "number" }]};
  var result = {};
  for (var index = 0; index < arr.items.length; ++index) {
    result[index] = formatItems(arr.items[index]);
  }
  console.log(result);
}

function formatItems(item, index) {
  return {
    type: "string",
    id: "item-"+index
  };
}

convertData();
```

Answer (score 2):

In ES6, you could [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the `arr.items` and [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) the resulting array inside `{}`. This creates an object with indices of array as properties

```js
function formatItems(item, index) {
  return { type: "string", id: "item-"+index }
}

const arr = { "items": [ {"type": "color"}, {"type": "number" }] };

const output = { ...arr.items.map(formatItems) } 
      
console.log(output)
```

Comment: Using the OP's `formatItems`, it's simply `let output = {...arr.items.map(formatItems)};` Nice!

Comment: I guess the OP needed an ES5 solution. Your ES2015+ one was way better than mine. :-) Can't believe I didn't think of that.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks, I updated the answer to what you mentioned because the contents of `formatItems` are [dummy according to OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56114845/reduce-array-of-objects-to-a-single-object-and-call-a-function-for-each-individu/56115131?noredirect=1#comment98863526_56114845)

Comment: Which improved it ever so slightly, but it was already a very good answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `initialValue` as empty `object` to reducer.

**Example:**

```
function convertData() {
 var arr = {"items": [ {"type": "color"}, {"type": "number" }]};
 const res = arr.items.reduce(function(acc, item, index) {
    const out = formatItems(item, index)

    //change this if you need an indexed keys, like acc[index] = out
    acc[out.id] = out
    return acc
 }, {});

   console.log(res);
}

function formatItems(item, index) {
  return {
    type: "string",
    id: "item-"+index
  }
}
convertData()
```